# The correct translation for " Casa de los Perros"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, méxico

What is the correct way to say "Casa de los Perros""

```
1 .- House of Dogs
2 .- House of the Dogs.
```

Here is [a link](http://www.plusesmas.com/genealogia/fotos_antiguas/sudamerica/mexico/guanajuato/imagen/88_25318.html) to the page with a photo of Casa de los Perros

Comment: I added the link to the page you provided, but I'm not sure if is the best link to illustrate the location you want to explain.

Comment: it directs to the wrong photo of what I was trying to show, and there are several Casa de los perros in different states in Mex. This is the one I was trying to show :  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35JbvrYmaSI

Comment: I used the link you provided on the first comment. You can always edit your own question, and substitute the link there with an updated one you want to use.

Comment: House of dogs would mean "Casa hecha de perros" :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the places receives than name for two sculptures of dogs that were brought from New York and placed on the upper part of the house (terrace).

In order to keep the meaning of the place the proper translation seems to be ["(The) House of **the** Dogs"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_reportedly_haunted_locations_in_Mexico), as can be seen in that wikipedia entry (I checked what "Casa de los Perros" was and after learning it is a location in Jalisco, Mexico I just googled "House dogs jalisco mexico". That was the first result).

Comment: So I guess you can call it "La Casa de los Perros" or " Casa de los perros" but my first question was I guess; is it : "The House of (the) Dogs" or "House of Dogs". Just a question that I have in mind.

Comment: In case is unclear, the first "the" is optional (**La** Casa de los perros vs. Casa de los Perros). That is why I put in in parenthesis. The second one is mandatory (so I put it in bold), if you want to keep the meaning of the name of the place. My understanding, from your question, is that you were asking about the second one.